# How can I install ubuntu-restricted-extras?

Tags: software-installation, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I searched for ubuntu-restricted-extras in app store. I didn't find it. I opened terminal and typed

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

but it said unable to find. I typed

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then certain something like a 500MB download started.

But although it sucessfully installed, I still can't play videos and songs.

Answer (score 2):

Installing the package is easy

Go to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats

click on the link "Click here to install the ubuntu-restricted-extras package"

apt:ubuntu-restricted-extras?section=universe?section=multiverse

To manually install, make sure you have enabled universe and multiverse

[How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)