# How can I run a .mkv file in VLC (or an equivalent)?

Tags: vlc, mkv

I have some .mkv files and I'm trying to play then in VLC. The audio works but the video does not (just a black screen).

I tried in the "Videos" program. There is video but its very choppy and not fluid.

I have installed the "snap" version of VLC then `snap run vlc`. That didn't change anything.

I tried to install ubuntu-restricted-extras but it doesn't seem to exist for 18.04.

Any ideas? This is getting frustrating!!

Comment: This link should help with extras package, probably why having trouble with mkv.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/936742/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-restricted-extras

Comment: What do you get when your run ```mediainfo yourfile.mkv | grep -i codec``` ? (you have to install the **mediainfo** package first).My VLC in ubuntu 18.04 plays mkv files well with the video codecs ```V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC```.Maybe it's a problem with the video codec.

Comment: @crip659 I installed the extras but they didn't changed anything unfortunately.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi My results are: V_MPEGH/ISO/HEVC.

Comment: @user203748 Try this : ```sudo apt-get install vlc-plugin-libde265``` . You have to add the PPA ```ppa:strukturag/libde265``` first